Optimal Strategy : Dice Game
I was asked this question in an interview:

You are given a fair dice.
You can roll the dice any number of times.
Your reward will be the sum of the face value of the dice on every roll.
But if the sum exceeds $10$ after any roll then your reward becomes $0$ and the game is stopped.

What is the optimal strategy to play this game ?.
But I was unable to approach this question. Hence help is required.

Please edit to include your efforts.  As a way to get started, consider what happens at (possible) future states of the game.  If you currently have $9$, it should be easy to argue that you ought to stop.  What about $8$?  Or $7$?  And so on.

Does "optimal strategy" refer to optimal in the sense of maximizing the expected reward?

We can determine the optimal strategy by letting our sum so far, $S$, dictate our decision. Trivially, $S < 4$ implies you roll again (no downside) and $S = 9$ implies you should stop rolling (no upside).
For the non-trivial cases, we can determine if rolling again is optimal by determining of the expected value of our sum after rolling is higher than our current sum.
We could think about this as a function $f(x) = E[reroll | S=x] - x$ where we would want to reroll for all values of $x$ where $f(x) > 0$. For $f(x)=0$, we are indifferent and rerolling has no change in EV. You can do the calculations pretty easily by hand and find that the expected value of rolling again for $S=5$ is $40 / 6 > 5$ and $S=6$ is $34 / 6 < 6$.
This function f is unimodal so for $S\le 5$, reroll, and for $S>5$, stay.
EDITED: Misread the question and thought it said including $10$.

My earlier comment was heuristic , not calculated. Hence it was wrong on the number. I updated my answer with calculations & $S=5$ is not "can do either" : It is actually "continue" , to get better reward.

I think for S <=5 reroll, but for value greater than than don't reroll. I'm basing my result on the equation that if we're at any particular sum such that n=10-S, n>=1 and n<=6 the incentive for reroll(gain) will be given as: (1/6 + 1/62+...+1/6n)-((6-n)/6)*S. For n=1,2,3,4 we will on an average lose but for n=5,6 we will gain on an average. Hence for S>5 we don't risk reroll else we are free to reroll.

I gave the calculation in Strategy C in my answer , @MdKaifFaiyaz , which will maximize the Expectation when we play multiple times while taking moderate risk. When we play Exactly Once , Strategy A is Optimal : We will never lose + We take no risk. Strategy B has high risk.

I made a mistake reading the question and thought it was including 10. This would make it optimal to reroll for S=5. Apologies

Interview Questions are mostly about what thinking you can give & what justifications you can give. Here are 3 ways to look at the Issue.
My Strategy A :
No Risk Approach + guaranteed reward
We roll it once , getting between $1$ & $6$ , inclusive.
Let that be $C$.

In Case $C$ is $5$ or more , then rolling again might give us $5+6=11$ & we lose everything. Hence we terminate & take our reward $C$.
In Case $C$ is $4$ or less , then rolling again might give us max $4+6=10$ & we will not lose everything. Hence we continue to throw.
The new number is added to $C$
We check whether or not to throw again , like we did earlier.

We will eventually terminate & collect reward $C$.
Eg : $C=1+2+1+6=10$ , $C=4+4=8$ , $C=6$ , $C=1+1+1+1+1=5$ , $C=2+2+5=9$ , $C=1+2+4=7$
Deterministically , I will get reward between $5$ & $10$ , around $7.5$
My Strategy B :
High Risk Approach + Moderate reward
When $C$ is $7$ , there is $50 \%$ Chance that I will roll $1,2,3$ to get new $C=8,9,10$ , while there is $50 \%$ Chance that I will roll $4,5,6$ to get $C=11,12,13$ which will make me lose everything.
Hence I will take risk when I have $C=7$ or less & terminate when I have $C=8$ or more.
I take the reward $C$ , though there is a $50-50$ chance that I will lose everything.
Probabilistically , I will get reward around $9$ ( not calculated this thoroughly ) , though $0$ could occur.
When I want to take less risk , I can terminate earlier at $C=5,6$.
When I want to take more risk , I can terminate later at $C=8,9$.
It is like Stock Market !
My Strategy C :
Moderate Risk Approach + Moderate reward
While A gives guarantees & B uses Probability+heuristics , we might want
to use Expectation to generate a new Strategy.
Criteria to terminate :
When we have $C=10$ , we can not improve , hence terminate at $C=10$
When we have $C=9$ , rolling again might give $10$ (when we throw $1$) otherwise we will get $0$. Expectation is $10/6=1.66$ , worse than not throwing , hence terminate at $C=9$
When we have $C=8$ , rolling again might give $9,10$ (when we throw $1,2$) otherwise we will get $0$. Expectation is $19/6=3.33$ , worse than not throwing , hence terminate at $C=8$
When we have $C=7$ , rolling again might give $8,9,10$ (when we throw $1,2,3$) otherwise we will get $0$. Expectation is $27/6=4.50$ , worse than not throwing , hence terminate at $C=7$
When we have $C=6$ , rolling again might give $7,8,9,10$ (when we throw $1,2,3,4$) otherwise we will get $0$. Expectation is $34/6=5.66$ , worse than not throwing , hence terminate at $C=6$
Criteria to Continue :
When we have $C=5$ , rolling again might give $6,7,8,9,10$ (when we throw $1,2,3,4,5$) otherwise we will get $0$. Expectation is $40/6=6.66$ , better than not throwing , hence continue at $C=5$
When we have $C=4$ , rolling again might give $5,6,7,8,9,10$ (when we throw $1,2,3,4,5,6$) there is no way we will get $0$. Expectation is $45/6=7.50$ , better than not throwing , hence continue at $C=4$
Likewise for $C=3,2,1,0$
SUMMARY :
Which Strategy we want to use will vary with our risk appetite & whether we can play the game multiple times.
Playing "Exactly Once" , Strategy A is Optimal , giving guarantee on the reward.
Playing multiple times with "high-risk = high-reward" thinking , Strategy B is Optimal.
Playing multiple times with "Maximize Expectation" thinking , Strategy C is Optimal.
